# Systematic name of OCS (COS)

Tags: nomenclature

What is the systematic name of carbonyl sulfide? My professor commented that the systematic name was "very odd" so he didn't bother to mention it. Is it really that odd? And what is it, actually?

I found the name ["Thioxomethanone"](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.9644.html). Is that really odd? From my limited knowledge, I've seen the root "thiol" before in describing something with a sulfur in it. So at least the root doesn't seem weird. I also see "oxo." There's an O in OCS.

Comment: well, "thioxomethanone" name surely is decipherable, like e.g. "benzene-1-ylwater" or "norcresol" for phenol :) but is it even organic compound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonyl_sulfide) lists the IUPAC name as "carbon oxide sulfide."  Odd? Sounds kind of logical to me.

Comment: Is IUPAC the same as systematic name?

Comment: Yes, it's the only system I'm aware of for naming compounds.

Comment: http://youtu.be/QBJk_L0NmMg?t=6m1s

Comment: I think this is what he came across: http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.9644.html

Comment: please be noted that the Wikipedia article was [improved](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Carbonyl_sulfide&diff=851743251&oldid=849807664) to contain *referenced* IUPAC names (see [my answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13789/systematic-name-of-ocs-cos/99821#99821))

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there's definitive answer to not-yet-asked question, whether this compound can be considered organic or inorganic compound.

While **organic** nomenclature books do not mention it (acording to the current rules it might be called **sulfanylidenemethanone**, which is somewhat absurd), official IUPAC **inorganic** chemistry nomenclature ([Red Book 2005](https://doi.org/10.1515/ci.2005.27.6.25), table IX, p. 292) lists two names for this compound:

- **carbonyl sulfide**
- **oxidosulfidocarbon**

Your mentioned (organic) systematic name thioxomethanone is just a variant of already mentioned sulfanylidenemethanone, as S= group's preferred name ("preselected prefix") is now sulfanylidene-<sup>*</sup> instead of thioxo- (rule P-15.5.3.3)

---

*) see analogy H<sub>2</sub>C=/H<sub>3</sub>C− methylidene-/methyl-, and
S=/HS− sulfanylidene-/sulfanyl- (older name: mercapto-)